# How to write Select query for selecting particular xml nodes in DB2 which occur multiple times?

Tags: sql, db2, xquery-sql

I have a XML structure as below:

```
<root>
    <firstChild>
        <a>
            <a1>someText</a1>
            <a2>someNumber</a2>
        <a>
        <a>
            <a1>someText1</a1>
            <a2>someNumber1</a2>
        <a>
        <a>
            <a1>someText2</a1>
            <a2>someNumber2</a2>
        <a>
        <a>
            <a1>someText3</a1>
            <a2>someNumber3</a2>
        <a>
    </firstChild>
</root>
```

I want to write a DB2 SQL which will return all application id which have a1 as someText1 and a2 as someNumber1.

For more information I have a table say APPLICATION which has application_xml as column. This column has all the xml documents as shown above and are stored against each application id.

Can someone please suggest.

I have tried below query but it did not succeed.

```
select XMLQUERY('copy $new := $application_xml
for $i in $new/root/firstChild/a[a1 = "someText1"], $new/root/firstChild/a[a2 = "someNumber1"]  
return $new') from application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I assume that the table has two columns application id (aid) and application_xml. As you want to return the application id the base structure of the query is

```
select aid from application
```

Now we need the condition of which rows qualify. You state that in the related XML document the elements a1 and a2 need to have a certain value. The function `xmlexists` is the one to use in the `WHERE` clause of SQL:

```
select aid from application
where xmlexists('$d/root/firstChild/a[a1 = "someText1" and a2 = "someNumber1"]' passing application_xml as "d")
```

The [XMLEXISTS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022228.html?lang=en) is used as filtering predicate. The "passing" clause tells DB2 to expect "application_xml" under the name "d" inside the XPath/XQuery expression. The XPath expression itself is looking for the path `/root/firstChild/a` and under a specific "a" both the condition for "a1" and "a2" need to be true. If you want a broader condition, there would be also ways to express that.

Comment: I understood your answer. But can you please point me to a good resource of DB2 XML query so that I am less held up syntactical issues.

Comment: You could start here in the DB2 Knowledge Center: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023895.html?lang=en